# Bootstrap Accordion with a table and dynamic number or rows

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, accordion

Having trouble getting Accordion collapse to work within a table and a dynamic number of rows. For some reason it is only collapsing the first item in the table and ignoring the following rows, even though I have the Id's for hidden rows set to a unique identifier (company number). The amount of rows that are in the table will be dynamic.

```
    <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Company Number</th>
            <th>View Documents</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Time Submitted</th>
            <th>Mark as Completed</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for job in todo %}
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ job.company_number }}" class="accordion-toggle">
                <td><a href="{% url 'company_detail' country_code=job.jurisdiction %}?company_number={{ job.company_number }}">{{ job.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ job.company_number }}</td>
                <td><a href="#{{ job.company_number }}" aria-expanded="true">View</button></td>
                <td>{{ job.jurisdiction }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.job_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.time_submitted|date:"d M Y"}}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'mark_as_completed' %}?job_id={{ job.id }}">Mark as Completed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div id="{{ job.company_number }}" class="accordion-body collapse">Hello there!</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Is it because you have aria-expanded="true" set for every row?

Comment: have just removed this and the same again - just works with the first row :(

Comment: See my snippet as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

The following test works for me with both rows. Is it possible that job.company_number has duplicate values? ID's must be unique for it to work correctly.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

   <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Company Number</th>
            <th>View Documents</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Time Submitted</th>
            <th>Mark as Completed</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
    
    <!-- Job 1 -->
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#company1" class="accordion-toggle">
                <td><a href="{% url 'company_detail' country_code=job.jurisdiction %}?company_number={{ job.company_number }}">{{ job.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ job.company_number }}</td>
                <td><a href="#{{ job.company_number }}" aria-expanded="true">View</button></td>
                <td>{{ job.jurisdiction }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.job_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.time_submitted|date:"d M Y"}}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'mark_as_completed' %}?job_id={{ job.id }}">Mark as Completed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div id="company1" class="accordion-body collapse">Hello there!</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
    <!-- Job 2 -->
            <tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#company2" class="accordion-toggle">
                <td><a href="{% url 'company_detail' country_code=job.jurisdiction %}?company_number={{ job.company_number }}">{{ job.name }}</a></td>
                <td>{{ job.company_number }}</td>
                <td><a href="#{{ job.company_number }}" aria-expanded="true">View</button></td>
                <td>{{ job.jurisdiction }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.job_type }}</td>
                <td>{{ job.time_submitted|date:"d M Y"}}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'mark_as_completed' %}?job_id={{ job.id }}">Mark as Completed</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div id="company2" class="accordion-body collapse">Hello there!</div>
                </td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Update: In response to your comment, would it be better to use job.id for the accordian id's like so?

```
<tr data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#{{ job.id }}" class="accordion-toggle">

                <td colspan="6" class="hiddenRow">
                    <div id="{{ job.id }}" class="accordion-body collapse">Hello there!</div>
                </td>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time on this - yes that works perfectly for me too. The Id's are definitely unique I have tested this and it's getting the different numbers - could it be an issue with my for each? As there will be a different amount of rows every time I cannot have a set id for each hidden row

Comment: It is hard to tell without seeing the data, but perhaps you could use job.id for the accordion data-target as I am guessing that will always be unique whereas a company could have multiple jobs for it? e.g. <div id="{{ job.id }}" class="accordion-body collapse">Hello there!</div>

Comment: Okay so we figured it out! Turns out if we added a string before the job.id it worked, e.g. data-target="#demo{{job.id}}" and id="demo{{job.id}}". So maybe the issue was that it can't start with a number?